# Sonarqube: Some rules classify as minor and info at the same time

Tags: sonarqube

We are using the community edition of Sonarqube together with Cpp-Check. As you can see from the picture that I added we have the issue that some rules classify as minor and info at the same time. We know that we added some company rules that are different from Sonarqube. But were could it come from that some rules classify differently? Should it be that way? If yes why? If no how can I fix the behaviour?

[image: Rule classifying as minor and info at the same time]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issues take on the characteristics of their originating rules *at the time the issues were opened*. So if I activate ruleA as a Blockers in my profile, and run an analysis, any issues raised by ruleA will be raised as Blockers. I then edit ruleA in my profile to Info and run an analysis where new issues are raised. Those new issues will be Info level. The first set of issues raised by ruleA *will not* be retroactively edited to make them Info. They will stay Blockers until and unless they're manually edited to change them.

Comment: Thank you very much - that sounds in deed plausible :-)

Comment: It seems as if the issue category is in fact updated if the category of the underlying rule is changed (e.g. from Minor to Info).

The issue category is only not updated if a category has been assigned manually for this particular issue before.